# How do I replace two or more instances of a character in an Excel string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For example, what function or combination of functions would I use to convert string 1, "this_is_a_string" to string 2, "this is a string"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use substitute.  Or if its a one off use find and replace dialogue box.

`=SUBSTITUTE(a1,"_"," ")`

Comment: Thank you! I was using the replace function, but couldn't figure out how to do more than one.